# How do I find the number of namespaces in Hazelcast?

Tags: java, cluster-computing, in-memory-database, hazelcast

Using ns  command i created a number of namespaces in my console. I have a problem now. I have created more than 5 namespaces and I have lost track of them ! I want to see the number of namespaces that I have created and their respective names.

Is there any command to find out the number of created namespaces in Hazelcast ?
Please help.!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the command line tool "instances" will do the job.
Programatically you can call hazelcastInstance.getInstances() which will return you the Collection of Instances.